# How to achieve the best possible performance with mutable data and real-time charts in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, chart.js, mobx

During the last couple of weeks I've researched and experimented quite a lot with different charting libraries - especially Highcharts and Chart.js - trying to squeeze the best possible performance out of them, only to be disappointed with the results.

**Mutability vs Immutability:**

First of all I decided to ditch Redux, since on the data/state part, I'm storing all datapoints as objects in an array in the form `[{x: sometimestamp, y: somenumber}]`

I ditched Redux as my state container, since making a copy for each insertion, would not perform well on a large scale. Imagine copying an array of 100000 objects, when all you wanted was to push a new datapoint object at the end of the array.

Also when the (user defined) maxCount is reached, I'm shifting the first item in the array, at the same time as pushing the new item to the end. That way the chart "moves" forward.

Since Redux with its immutable way of doing things, didn't quite cut it, I chose to go with MobX. The mutable state of dataobjects is being shifted and pushed as it should, so now my only job is to try and get it rendered in the chart component each time new data arrives (roughly each second in the real code).

**The use case**

So.. let's say you store a new datapoint each second for 24 hours = 86400 datapoints. That is the extreme case, usually I'd need no more than 3600 points (the latest hour) on a moving real-time chart. Sometimes though it could me useful with multiple series (usually 2-5, but indeally up to 10, which would mean 36000 points).

Typically I'd show 2-4 charts on screen at the same time, each with support for multiple series such as mentioned above and each of them would update every second or so, when new data arrives.

**Observations from benchmarks**

Right now, I'm seeing very high CPU utilization when trying just to show a single chart with less than 2000 points. Even with 20 points the percentage seems a bit too much, eventhough animations are disabled.

**React way, vs ref + lib internal API / mutations**

For a long time it bugged me that the react-way of handling charts is by passing data as a prop. So far to good. My problem with it was that this data prop would only be recognized by react.render as "changed" and thus rerendered - IF you copy the entire array of datapoints. This works well for small arrays, but not with thousands of objects.

I tried to make a repo to show this here:

**ChartJs (react-way)** version: https://github.com/BruceL33t/mutable-high-performance-real-time-charts-in-react/tree/chartjs-reactish

So using MobX and mutable data, I sought out to find a solution where I could avoid having to copy the datapoints for each update. The only real solution I could see was to make a ref to the charting library and call its internal api `addPoint(point)` (highcharts) or `datasets[0].data` (chartjs) directly followed by a redraw() / update() on the chart directly. This way the component wont use react's render function after the initial render.

I would have thought this would be much faster, since we're "closer to the metal" and mutating the chart data directly, but ***I saw no real performance improvement using ref***.

**Chartjs** version: https://github.com/BruceL33t/mutable-high-performance-real-time-charts-in-react/tree/master

**Highcharts** version: https://github.com/BruceL33t/mutable-high-performance-real-time-charts-in-react/tree/highcharts

**Try the examples above**

In the index.js try experimenting with lowering the interval from 1000 to 100ms (line 103) and set a maxSize of in line 90 to Sensor(2000) and run with your task manager open, and all other tabs closed and monitor cpu usage for chrome. As you can see we're getting close 60% cpu utilization as we close in on the 2000 datapoints. Again - this is without animations. With animations, it starts around 40 and going up from there.

**Any ideas for increasing performance (lower CPU usage)**

Is it that much work for the cpu to move points in a canvas each second, or what am I doin wrong? Do you know of any other charting libraries which handles real-time charts with thousands of points each seconds? And how do you generally approach taking your mutable array of datapoints (from MobX or whatever) and render it in a chart in React? Any good practice to follow when going "off grid" with React in search for more "bare metal" power. Any other way than using ref or good patterns to follow?

**Edit:**

Although I've not tested them but from the looks of it, the following charts looks to perform a lot better than the other chart libraries I've come across so far.

- [rgraph](https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/docs/updating-charts-dynamically.html)
- [Canvasjs](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/updating-chart-options/)
- [d3](http://signalfx.github.io/charting-library-comparison/d3/streaming-line-chart.html)
- [Dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/dynamic-update)

I'm going to test them now, and update once I have tried them out.

Comment: Same problem, but i'm using apexchart with react .. any recommandation plz

Answer (score 0):

Every time you shift an array you will need to move the position of every item therefore you might as well copy the whole array. There are a couple of things you can do to work around this bottleneck. Number one is to accept less data points. Your user's screen is less pixels wide than the amount of points you want to render so  unless you have a very dense graph with a lot of lines, you can probably already visually get away with a lot less data points.

The problem still remains the same though so you're going to have to do more trickery. Something you could do would be to find a way to give indexes to your chart library that way you can just append the array and tell the chart to only render starting at the index equal to the amount of items appended to your array. The chart would still have to rerender every point but we're getting there.

The best solution would be to skip the last trick and find a chart library that has the ability to either render new points on the fly or when given a new array of points diffs it to only render the new ones AND will render those new points to the right of the old points therefor not rerendering the rest of the points. To get it to look visually what you want you will have to put the chart into a horizontal scroll view then disable scrolling and keep it glued to the right. You will have to make the legend and metrics yourself though.

Hope someone has a better solution for you hahaha good luck.

Comment: Actually I just found out that d3 and Dygraphs can pretty much render 2000 datapoints (shifting / pushing) at 50ms around 4-5% cpu usage. CanvasJs and rgraph is decent as well, so I guess the rendering part is pretty clear now. Maybe except the most elegant way to use external 3rd lib api's with react instead of react.render. I'm just amazed I had to look so long down the list to find some proper charts. :) Good point about shift not being better than copying the entire array - I guess if insisting on mutable data I need to switch to a https://github.com/petkaantonov/deque instead of an array.